# Class 'BeyondCode\DumpServer\DumpServerServiceProvider' not found when I make composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.8, laravel-artisan

I'm deploying my Laravel application and want to optimize the autoload, normally I would run the command

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
```

This is an application that runs **Laravel 5.8**. I am getting the following error:

> In Application.php line 662:
> Class 'BeyondCode\DumpServer\DumpServerServiceProvider' not found
> Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the
> post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do not have development dependencies on the laravel-dump-server, remove the following line from composer.json.

```
"beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0".
```

Then run the following command.

```
composer install
```

Or, even easier, just run the following.

```
composer remove --dev beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
```

Comment: Ok. when i do it. I have this warring for `composer` *`Dependency "laravel/framework" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring`* and the same error too.

Comment: And/or 'composer dump-autoload'

Comment: The command fails and show same error. I have locate `BeyondCode\\DumpServer\\DumpServerServiceProvider` in the bootstrap cache folder and when i remove the `packages.php` cache in `bootstrap/cache`. The `artisan clear-compiled` is ok.

Comment: Normally, I had to do a `artisan clear-complied` before installing the `composer --optimize-autoloader --no-dev.`

Answer (score 4):

In my case I have done below steps

1. Delete **vendor** folder
2. Run: `composer self-update --1`
3. And again run: `composer install`
4. Then you can run any command you want

Comment: This worked for me. But the problem happened to me when I was using composer 2 in an old project.

Comment: What do you get when you run `composer self-update --2` after you delete **Vendor** folder?

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
```

if this not work try and getting error undefine index: Name
Solution 2

```
Step1: `composer self-update --1`

Step2: composer install
```

Bingo...!!!

Answer (score 0):

A detail around this issue has been written in one of the GitLab issues on
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/736

This issue explain why this dev package creates problem on your build server.

For me, The issue resolved after I've added this in composer.json

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "gcp-build": [
            "composer install --no-dev"
        ]
    }
}
```

This will remove all the dev dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I simply do

```
composer update
```

and then I redo again

like myself I run

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score -1):

You may need to run composer update with the `--no-plugins` option.

```
composer update --no-plugins
```